# Are there any terminal emulators that support status line using the terminfo defintion?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

Once upon a time, there was terminal emulation software that supported status lines in the terminfo definition, à la:

```
tput hs
tput tsl
tput fsl
```

Is such a thing to be found any more?

Specifically **not** talking about tmux, byobu, screen, et cetera, et al.

Comment: You could, maybe, use `expect` to write a wrapper to do this.